# Hibernate - Querying for a property that may not exist

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

Thanks in advance for any help offered.

I have some objects with a property, say 'deleted'. I am trying to find a way to filter properties within a Hibernate Container without having to instantiate a subcontainer for the classes that have this property.

If I use something like:

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("deleted", true));
```

then I of course get errors when an object that does not contain this property pass through the container.

Is there a Restriction, Alias, Projection, Whichever that can determine whether or not this property exists and apply the restriction if it does?

Answer (score 0):

No. But you could write it yourself by using [`SessionFactory.getClassMetadata(Class entityClass)`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html#getClassMetadata%28java.lang.Class%29) and check if there is a `deleted` property in the class (of type boolean).